# How to execute Rake tasks in parallel

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rake

I have cucumber tests to run on multiple devices and emulators at the same time. While this I am able to achieve using multiple jobs in the jenkins and having it parameterized, I do not consider this to be the best approach since in the future we can have more devices added and I do not want to have endless jobs in jenkins.

While I tried using rake tasks, I find it executes sequentially than in parallel

These are the two rake tasks:

```
def run_cucumber(profile)
  Cucumber::Rake::Task.new do |t|
    t.profile = profile
  end
  Rake::MultiTask[:cucumber].invoke
end

task 'Device1' do |t|
  run_cucumber('MotoZ2Play')
end
task 'Device2' do |t|
  run_cucumber('MotoG5Plus')
end
```

And here is how I initiated Parallel rake using `multi task`

```
multitask 'build_parallel' => ['Device1', 'Device2']
```

This seems to again not execute in parallel but in sequential order.

I tried implementing parallel tests gem, with the code:

```
Parallel.map([:Device1,:Device2,:Device3,:Device4,:Device5]) {|task| Rake::Task[task].invoke }
```

but this appears to execute random scenarios in my cucumber feature file, We wanted scenarios to be executed in the order we wrote.

How do I achieve parallel rake tasks?

Update:

Solved it by using 
`Parallel.each` instead of `Parallel.map`

Comment: Honestly, I am lost. “in parallel” and “in the order we wrote” is not achievable simultaneously, these goals contradict each other.

Comment: I guess you got it wrong, by order we wrote in the sense, I dont mean "in the order we want it to run", but this means the set of scenarios(test cases) executing one by one in all the devices in parallel. For eg: I have Testcases A, B , C , D , E  each in two rakes X and Y, I would want these X and Y to run in parallel executing A , B , C , D , E and not  E , B , C , A , D

Comment: this question is sort of misleading, because you already know how to run rake tasks in parallel. If you can make multiple device instances from a single ruby thread, then you can have each test case run its code for each device in parallel .. you don't necessarily need to run the whole rake task in parallel, if that makes sense

Comment: @maxpleaner This actually let me put `parallel.each([:Device1, :Device2])` instead of `parallel.map` thereby producing instances as needed across devices. Thanks. got it work :)

Comment: To add a bit of extra thought here. In Jenkins, not sure exactly which version introduced it, but you can run parallel tasks on nodes now. Which means you are using 1 executor running multiple threads on nodes in that executor. Of course you will need to be mindful of how many tasks you are running as you could overload the executor. Another option could be for the Jenkins job to kick off x number of jobs on different slaves, Say EC2 instances in AWS, each with its own defined config.

Comment: Multiple machines is not my cup of tea as the management is not approving of budget to support all of em at this moment.

In Jenkins are you taking about creating new jobs and keeping it parameterized?

Answer (score 1):

There is a gem called `parallel_tests` https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests, which allows you to create custom rake tasks and to run them in parallel. 
You can also specify num of CPUs you wanna use.

So here is the some simple example I just did:

```
namespace :my_task do
  task :a => :environment do
    100.times {
      puts "A"
    }
  end

  task :b => :environment do
    100.times {
      puts "B"
    }
  end

  task :c => :environment do
    Rake::Task["my_task:a"].execute
    Rake::Task["my_task:b"].execute
  end
end
```

And the output is smthg like:

```
B
B
B
B
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
A
A
A
A
A
A
...
```

I hope that helps.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! Shall Try this out. This seems more appropriate solution without heavy dependency on external libraries again

Comment: Yes exactly, basically it used to be use for speed up test suites but authors left a space for using it in some other circumstances like this one for example. It does good job for us on several areas.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use the `drake` gem, which is a fork of `rake` that adds concurrency support. I don't know why `multitask` didn't work for you, but the main problem with that is that you cannot specify the amount of concurrency you want to run a Rakefile with. With drake, you can, through the -j option. It's similar to `make`'s -j option.

Install with:

```
 gem install drake
```

Suppose you have a Rakefile like this:

```
task :a do
  sleep 5
  puts "a"
end
```

If you run `drake -j2` then it'll run with a concurrency of 2, and so both "a" and "b" will print simultaneously after 5s.

But if you run `drake` (or `drake -j1`) then you'll see only "a" after 5s, then "b" after another 5s.

Drake is no longer maintained, but it still works great. I've been using it for 8 years now to develop Phusion Passenger.

Comment: Thanks! I ll soon try this out!